# How do I prevent ip6 usage on net smtp

Tags: perl

My Net::SMTP code on Windows 2012 / StrawberryPerl is crapping out and I think it's because Perl is trying to use IPv6 addresses and my local MS SMTP server isn't running on IPv6. The following works, but if I use "localhost" or the FQDN the Net::SMTP->new() fails and $@ contains "Bad address"

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('127.0.0.1',
                           Timeout => 30,
                           Debug   => 1,
                          );
```

Also, if I use the FQDN of a remote SMTP server (Windows 2008 / IMail), it works.

Both the local & remote servers have SMTP listening on port 25 only for IPv4.

Is there a way to force IPv4 within my script? I thought about disabling IPv6 within Windows but I read that it isn't recommended. What else can I try to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try forcing the dns resolution to ipv4 with `Domain => AF_INET}`, i.e.:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('FQDN',
                           Timeout => 30,
                           Domain => AF_INET,
                           Debug   => 1,
                          );
```

---

> If "Domain" is not given, AF_UNSPEC is assumed, that is, both AF_INET
>   and AF_INET6 will be both considered when resolving DNS  names.
>   AF_INET6 is prioritary.

SRC: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1127249

Comment: I was hopeful but I get the same results - "Bad address" when used with "localhost" and "Invalid argument" when used with FQDN of local machine. Also, I don't get any debug output like I do when it succeeds.